# What 7zip settings to compress very large partition image?

Tags: backup, compression, 7-zip

I have 77 GB big partition backup image in single file and I'd like to compress it quickly. It should compress very well even on worst settings, but choosing GZIP with "Fastest" setting takes about ~1 hour. How can I speed up the process?

More details: The image file is raw, binary copy of partitions (output of linux ddrescue tool).
I store the file on WD hard drive connected with USB 3.

Comment: Is the process CPU bound or IO bound?

Comment: Does the partition backup has some kind of compression already in it, or is it raw data? If it already has a compression in it, it will likely not compress much, so looking into this might not be the best option.

Comment: To explain that a bit more: If you have a fairly normal rotating disk which is doing nothing else but ready data for your compression program you might get about 100MB/s. With that speed 77GB should take about 13 minutes just to read it.

Writing is usually slower. Especially when you are also reading from that disk. 

Which means that even without any compression you would need about half an hour just to copy the data. Possibly more. Possible most of the ~1h you see now. If that is the case then you are IO bound.

Also, LPChip has a good point. Already compressed data will not compress again.

Comment: LPChip: it's completely raw data, without any compression. I used linux's dd tool to copy partitions.

Comment: A note though. Although you do state its raw data, the fact is that it is a backup image of an apparently used partition. So, the compression ratio and speed will depend on the contents within which if they were already compressed (executables, pictures, videos) will stifle the compression process.

Comment: Are you trying to save it on the same (USB) drive you're reading it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regards to improving compression speed:

1. Parallelize it. http://blog.codinghorror.com/file-compression-in-the-multi-core-era/.
2. Different compression algorithms (like lzop) are very fast.
3. Get optimized zlib implementations. Google intel zlib, for instance.

In regards to improving read speed:

- You will only get close to your rated disk throughput if you are using an SSD or if you are reading from your disk in "block" mode. This has to do with the file seeks associated with reading small files.
- In linux you would use something like `dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=1m | lzop > my_backup.dd.lzop`